# Is there a faster alternative to GDI GetPixel()?

Tags: .net, windows, gdi+, gdi, winapi

I'm using `GetPixel()` from gdi32.dll in a .NET app to sample the colour of a  pixel anywhere on the screen. It works ok but it is a major performance bottleneck for me.

Is there a faster way of doing it?

Comment: What kind of usage do you need? It might be worthwhile to grab a region on the screen and then sample pixels from that.

Comment: My app allows the user to sample colour from anywhere on the screen (outside of my app) in realtime. +1 Good idea about restricting to a region: I'll see if I can do that.

Answer (score 12):

Fast access to pixels are possible using `LockBits()` method of the `Bitmap`. This will return to you an object containing a pointer to the start of the pixel data and you can use unsafe code to access the memory.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150330113356/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I've upvoted because that's a useful article for some other image manipulation I'm doing. But it doesn't help me get the colour of a pixel anywhere on the screen (unless I take a screenshot first, which isn't what I want).

Answer (score 9):

`GetPixel` is slow for two reasons:

1. Since you're polling the screen - every call to `GetPixel` leads to a transaction to the video driver, which in turn takes the pixel data from the video memory.

   In constrast using `GetPixel` on DIBs is very much faster.
2. Anyway `GetPixel` does several things, including coordinates clipping/transformations and etc.

So that if you're using to query many pixel values at once - you should try to arrange this in a single transaction to GDI / video driver.

Using GDI you should create a DIB of the adequate size (see `CreateDIBSection`). After creation you'll be given a direct pointer to the image bits data. Then copy the image part onto your DIB (see `BitBlt`). Also don't forget to call `GdiFlush` before you actually check the contents of the DIB (since video drivers may do asynchronous drawing).

Using GD+ you may actually do the same, with a bit simpler syntax.