# Xaml converter for blending color to icons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have lots of icons in black & white color. My goal is to make a converter that receives those icons and blend the icon bitmap with another color, specified as a converter parameter. For example:

```
<Window Icon="{Binding Path=MyBlackAndWhiteIcon,
                       Converter={StaticResource myColorConverter},
                       ConverterParameter=FFCC00"/>
```

Can someone give me a clue on how do I properly build this converter?

PS: I knwo how to make converters. The question is about this specific converter, since "MyBlackAndWhiteIcon" is typically a string pointing to an resource image.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by 'blend' but if it means replacing either white or black with another color, this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17209284/3047078

Comment: By "blend" I mean "to mix".

Answer (score 1):

First, put this at the top of your page: `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;`.  You need this for the `IValueConverter` class.

Next, read these webpages about converters:

http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html
http://tech.pro/tutorial/806/wpf-tutorial-binding-converters

These pages are what taught me how to create my converters.

Here is a sample converter:

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

public class FromobjectToToobjectConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Converting code here
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // Convert back here
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to make converters. The question is about this specific converter, which is quite non trivial.