# Bitmap class not found in UWP windows 10

Tags: c#, bitmap, windows-10, uwp

I am developing an image processing app for windows 10. I have searched online related to the image processing. I have found many resources that use Bitmap class for manipulating images. But in uwp, there is no such class exists. When I try to use it in my code, it says Generate Bitmap class.

Is there any alternative to this class in uwp?

Or I am missing any reference of Bitmap class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was developing an app not so long ago that needed the features of the Bitmap class. I sadly realized as you just did that it's not available under WinRT/UWP. All we have is Bitmap, WriteableBitmap as Edgaras suggested, and - thank the heavens- [WriteableBitmapEx](https://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/). It's a very good library providing a lot of image processing functions. It helped me a lot and solved all of my problems. Hope it will help you too!

Answer (score 3):

Try to have a look on this WriteableBitmap class: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br243259

Comment: Ya, I am already using it, but it doesn't provide all the properties and functionality that Bitmap class provide.