# Alternative of Bitmap (System.Drawing) in Windows Universal Application

Tags: c#, bitmap, arm, win-universal-app, intptr

I am developing a Windows Universal Application that will be running on ARM Architecture(**RaspberryPi 3, OS: Windows IoT**).

The problem i am facing is that **UWP** doesn't allow a lot of standard .Net libraries like **"System.Drawing"**

I currently have an **IntPtr** which contains the raw data for an image and i need to use it as **Bitmap** which of course is not possible in this scenario.  Is there any possible alternative for it.

I have looked for **BitmapImage** but didn't found any solution to it.

I have also tried Converting the **IntPtr** to **Byte[]** but then Converting array to **Image** or **BitmapImage** is not Possible in UWP.

Please Go Easy on me as i am newbie on C# Programming.

All I want is any Type of Bitmap or Image from an IntPtr

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34837456/bitmap-class-not-found-in-uwp-windows-10

Comment: That is not **relevant** to my Question. I need an image from IntPtr...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To conver the `IntPtr` to `Byte[]`, we can use the [`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146625.aspx) method. It copies data from a one-dimensional, managed 8-bit unsigned integer array to an unmanaged memory pointer.

Then we can use the [`WriteableBitmap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap) class to set the Byte[] to `WriteableBitmap`.

> The image source data of a WriteableBitmap is an underlying pixel buffer. PixelBuffer cannot be written to directly, however, you can use language-specific techniques to access the buffer and change its contents.
>
> To access the pixel content from C# or Microsoft Visual Basic, you can use the AsStream extension method to access the underlying buffer as a stream.

For more info, refer [Remarks of the WriteableBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap#remarks).

To Convert the `WriteableBitmap` to `BitmapImage`, we should be able to encode the stream from `WriteableBitmap`.

For example:

```
private byte[] managedArray;

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/sunset.jpg")).OpenReadAsync();
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();
    byte[] buffer = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
    unsafe
    {
        fixed (byte* p = buffer)
        {
            IntPtr ptr = (IntPtr)p;
            managedArray = new byte[buffer.Length];
            Marshal.Copy(ptr, managedArray, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
    await bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream().WriteAsync(managedArray, 0, managedArray.Length);
    InMemoryRandomAccessStream inMemoryRandomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, inMemoryRandomAccessStream);
    Stream pixelStream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
    byte[] pixels = new byte[pixelStream.Length];
    await pixelStream.ReadAsync(pixels, 0, pixels.Length);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)bitmap.PixelWidth, (uint)bitmap.PixelHeight, 96.0, 96.0, pixels);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.SetSource(inMemoryRandomAccessStream);
    MyImage.Source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to append more, but I can't edit comments yet, and SO automatically made my original reply a comment. Basically it looks like your predicament is a common one, but you have to look into a third party solution.