# Changing the color of pixles of an Image in c#

Tags: c#, .net, image, winforms

I am trying to replace black pixels with red in an image. Here is my image [My_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZOPV.jpg)

Here is my code

```
public static Bitmap ChangeColor(Bitmap scrBitmap)
{            
    Color newColor = Color.Red;
    Color actualColor;            
    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(scrBitmap.Width, scrBitmap.Height);

    for (int i = 0; i < scrBitmap.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < scrBitmap.Height; j++)
        {
            actualColor = scrBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);

            if (actualColor.R == 0 && actualColor.G == 0 && actualColor.B == 0)
                newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(actualColor.A, Color.Red));
        }
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

On Load

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"D:\test.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = ChangeColor(image);
```

I just want to change the color of the black background to red but it's not working. What am I missing ?

Edit: I tried the solution of [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208254/how-to-change-pixel-color-of-an-image-in-c-net%3Cbr%3E%3Cbr%3E) but it changes the color of the whole image.

Edit2: I tried @JonasH solution

```
if (0.3 * actualColor.R + 0.59 * actualColor.G + 0.11 * actualColor.B < 10)
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(actualColor.A, Color.Red));
                    else
                        newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actualColor);
```

It worked but not perfectly. Some pixels which are not pure black but close enough to black are still not changed. Here is the [image: Result]

Comment: There are many pixels in the background that look black but their value is not (0,0,0) which you compare against.

Comment: @wohlstad you are right, how can I compare the exact color and replce it to my desired color ?

Comment: You can try to change all pixels wihch are close enough to black (e.g. r<5 && g < 5 && b < 5), but it might produce some artifacts on the border.

Comment: You are not copying the non-"black" pixels to the new image.

Comment: *Never* make posts with "But it's not working". *Always* describe the result you get, and what result you expected.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is that you create a new bitmap, but do not copy the color for non black pixels. So you probably should do:

```
if (actualColor.R == 0 && actualColor.G == 0 && actualColor.B == 0)
       newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(actualColor.A, Color.Red));
else
    newBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, actualColor);
```

An alternative would be to update the source bitmap in-place instead of creating a new one.

You might also want to change the color checks to something like

```
if (0.3 * actualColor.R + 0.59 * actualColor.G + 0.11*actualColor.B < threshold)
```

To include all pixels with a luminosity lower than some threshold

Comment: @JohasH I tried your solution but it's dosen't help either. Actually main issue is with this line `if (actualColor.R == 0 && actualColor.G == 0 && actualColor.B == 0)`.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi That line looks correct to me, *assuming* the actual color is **completely** black. It might be fine in created images, like a graph in your example, but is typically not appropriate for photos or compressed images.

Comment: Actually, if you check my attached image, not every part is pure black. I want to change the color which is pure or close enough to black.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi I did check your example image, but the background seem pure black to me, with exception of compression artifacts, that I cannot tell if they are present in the original image, or added by the image host.

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi again, if you posted the actual result instead of "It's not working", we would not have to guess as much as what the actual problem is.

Comment: check my update.